# Is it okey to publish app on the Appstore with warnings from Unity

Tags: xcode, app-store, warnings, publish

I've heard that if you want to publish your app to the App Store, it's okay to have warnings from Xcode as long as they're not critical to the apps stablitity or performance. Of course, getting rid of them is the best option, but in this case, there are over 999+ warnings generated by a third-party app.

In my case is that I'm working on an app in Unity, and I'm getting a lot of Unity-generated warnings that I assume are benign, but I don't want to risk delaying the app's review process.

I receive the following warnings:

-This function declaration is not a prototype

-Code will never be executed

-All paths trough this function will call itself

-Unused function

-OSAtomicCompareAndSwap32Barrier is deprecated

Is there an app that has been allowed entry to the AppStore with these warnings? It it okey for me to publish the app on AppStore with these warnings or how should I approach this issue?

Thank you

Mike

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible best approach is to fix all warnings.

Anyway you are uploading `.ipa` file (compiled iOS application with some resources) to the App Store so Apple will not be looking at your source code and can't see these warnings.